# retrieve single value from php

Tags: php, html

I need to retrieve a single value from a php file inside an html doc but the problem is the php file is called later on, past the point where I want to include that value.

**eg:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
<head>
<title><? php echo $pro_title ?></title> <!-- Can't retrieve value -->
<meta name='Description' content='<? php echo $pro_title ?>' /> <!-- Can't retrieve value -->
<meta name='Keywords' content='<? php echo $pro_title ?>' /> <!-- Can't retrieve value -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header -->
<?php include ("header.html") ?>
<!-- Content Area Start -->
<?php include ('product.php') ?> <!-- Okay --> 
<!-- Content Area End --> 
<!-- Footer -->
<?php include ("footer.html") ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to reference that single php value without including the whole file, as well as keeping the content where its included?

Comment: What do you need exactly? Explain please.

Comment: Can you explain where / when you wish to capture the value of a particular variable? To what end?

Comment: Are you trying to say that the value of $pro_title is set within `product.php`? In which case, post the contents from `product.php` also.... should be straightforward

Comment: Sorry if its confusing. Basically I was echoing everything (hardcoded header and footer) and just including the php in a bare html doc but unfortunately there is a function inside the header.html that I need which won't work inside an echo statement, so I segregated the header and footer from the php and just included the php as content after the head.

Comment: RamRaider Yes, this is exactly right. I need to grab that value ($pro_title) and place it in the head to create the page title, keywords and content before I include the whole of the php file.

Comment: do you mean value is in ```product.php``` and you want to access that value even before you're ```require```ing it? If so, you've to change your structure, you've to ```require``` the file first, then access that value, and if you're ```echo```ing the value, you've to change them to variables and echo later on the body.

Comment: Thanks Nischal. Are you saying that <?php require ?> means I can source the file without displaying the contents unlike  <?php include ?>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in product.php you have some query or logic that help you to retrieve the $pro_title, maybe, if you dont want to refactory your page, you should cut this logic and put on another php file (eg: product_header.php) and then include it on top.
The variable inside product_header.php can be used later on if you need it on product.php script.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this as my php file was just running a while loop, so I added a function above it and then called this function in my html body area as the content. Then I added another function in my php underneath the original one for just the title and echoing $title.

Sorry to bother you all but you know when you just feel stuck, its like being lost in the woods, scary!!
Regards,
Steve